Built in keyboard does not work with Ubuntu on new ASUS Expertbook
Model: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. ASUS EXPERTBOOK B2502CVA_B2502CVA
OS: Ubuntu 24.04 LTS
Kernel: Linux 6.8.0-35-generic
I purchased a new Asus Expertbook with windows preinstalled. I installed Linux mint and the keyboard would not work, even though it does work in the UEFI. This message flashed on startup: "failed to enable keyboard on io series" (likely not verbatim). I decided to install Ubuntu (I was torn between Ubuntu and Mint in the first place) and on Ubuntu the keyboard does not work either. A wireless keyboard does work (linux mint wireless keyboard did not work). The touchpad does not work before logging in to my account. I am unaware if an error message flashes on startup with Ubuntu, text is displayed although too briefly to read.
Any help is appreciated I am new to Linux, I always used windows and am looking to switch over.
